# php to extract a substring before numbers in a word

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract a Substring before numbers in a word, For example: to get `ibm` from `ibm0987323123123a`, any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yep, my suggestion is "learn how to write RegExp".

Comment: This is basic. Like @ElonThan said, [get learning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: You need a basic understanding to write basic code have you try to slove it your self ??

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]*/i', "ibm0987323123123a", $matches);


print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with `preg_match`

```
$string  = 'ibm0987323123123a';

preg_match('/^([a-z]+)([0-9a-z]+)$/i', $string, $matches);
```

#### Output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'ibm0987323123123a' (length=17)
  1 => string 'ibm' (length=3)
  2 => string '0987323123123a' (length=1
```

Comment: Matched `thisansweriswrong` what're you expecting?

Comment: @ColeJohnson My local was `0-9a-zA-Z` sorry. It matched success with questioner `ibm` and yours now

Comment: @ColeJohnson There's the `i` modifier there which ignores cases. Though the input string might also contain non-alphanumeric characters (OP didn't specify) and this is what will break the regex.

Comment: Well, now it's pointless to have the ignore case......

Comment: @Jerry good point, thx

Comment: @Jerry my bad. Didn't notice that. However, the other answer is better as instead of checking unneededly past what is needed, it just scans up to the first non-alpha character.

Comment: @ColeJohnson You can show better answer by upvoting :)